# Why 2 time i=0 in Thread output in below Java code? What happened if we create multiple thread?? Why?

Tags: java, multithreading

public class MyThread extends Thread{

```
static int i=0;
public void run()
{
    for(;i<10;i++)
    {
        System.out.println("i = " + i);
    }
}
```

}

//Main Class
public class ThreadTest {

```
public static void main(String... s) {

    MyThread th1=new MyThread();
    th1.start();

    MyThread th2=new MyThread();
    th2.start();


}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean "not defined"? Do you mean "it gives different output each time"? That'll happen with shared values that you read and write non-atomically.

Comment: Do you mean "Why does it print `i = 0` 2 times"? That'll happen with shared values that you read and write non-atomically.

Comment: Please update question in a concluded way and explain it brief in post body

Comment: You should read the [Java Essentials Concurrency lesson](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html), especially the page about [thread interference.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interfere.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can run twice into the System.out.println block at nearly the same time. Then you get twice the output 0. Nothing prevents the threads from the running the run method at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking question around visibility and atomicy.
The value of i can be cached in the processor cache and increased value is not guaranteed to be propagated to shared memory immediately. So you are getting competently unpredictable results. Also i++ is not Atomic and i addition to that printl is separate operation.

For visibility only use volatile. For complete  correctness use Atomic variables.